Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources' Error
I have a flutter project that I was working on for past 1 month, suddenly it started showing me this error. I have tried updating SDK version from 33 to 34

also flutter pub clean, flutter pub update, flutter run
still getting this error

I have tried updating dependencies,
change SDK version,
update the min sdk version in app/build.gradle
